# Getting 7-Zip error - Unable to pass File-names with spaces to Process.Start() method

Tags: c#, 7zip

I need to pass .zip file location into `files` parameter in the below c# code.

If the file name DOES NOT CONTAIN spaces, everything is working fine. But, if the file name DOES CONTAIN spaces, it is throwing below error.

> Cannot find archive

Below is my code: Can anybody please suggest me how can I solve this problem?

```
        static void UnzipToFolder(string zipPath, string extractPath, string[] files)
    {
        string zipLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["zipLocation"];            

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string sourceFileName = string.Empty;
            string destinationPath = string.Empty;
            var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            sourceFileName = Path.Combine(zipPath, file);
            destinationPath = Path.Combine(extractPath, name);

            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processStartInfo.FileName = zipLocation;
            processStartInfo.Arguments = @"x " + sourceFileName + " -o" + destinationPath;
            processStartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to somebody for down vote without even telling me the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes around the file paths:

```
processStartInfo.Arguments = "x \"" + sourceFileName + "\" -o \"" + destinationPath + "\"";
```

Or for readability (with C# 6):

```
processStartInfo.Arguments = $"x \"{sourceFileName}\" -o \"{destinationPath}\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

All filenames and paths which contain spaces must be quoted.

Next, regarding your question, how about stating the path like:

7z a -tzip C:\abc\zipfilename C:\"Program files"\DirectoryOrFile